# Exponential generating function wilf 3.12

Tags: generating-functions

Fix $k>0$. Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of permutations of $n$ letters whose longest cycle is length $k$. Find the exponential generating function of ${f(n,k)}$ for $n≥0$ for fixed $k$.

I know that if $F(n,k)$ is the number of n-permutations whose cycles have lengths $≤ k$, then F has the egf $\exp\left(\frac{x+\cdots+x^k}{k}\right)$. But $f(n,k)$ counts those whose longest cycle is length $k$, so if $k≥1, ~~f(n,k)=F(n,k)-F(n,k-1)$, and the required egf is

$$\exp\left(\dfrac{x+...+x^{k-1}}{k-1}\right) \cdot\exp\left(\dfrac{x^k}k-1\right).$$

Can you help fill in the details. This is from Wilfs Generatingfunctionology.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong formula for $F(n,k)$. It should be
$$\exp \left( x + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \dots + \frac{1}{k} x^{k} \right)$$

and the final formula for $f(n,k)$ is also incorrect. It should be
$$\exp \left(x + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + \dots + \frac{1}{k-1} x^{k-1} \right) \cdot \left[ \exp \left( \frac{1}{k} x^k \right) -1 \right]$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Where do you get F(n,k)

Comment: @SammyCowgill That's the formula stated in the solution to exercise 3.12 in *generatingfunctionology*. I added the $x^2$ term for clarity. In your post, you seem to have erroneously inserted some parentheses. If you understand sections 3.5 ("Permutations and their cycles") and 3.7 ("A subclass of permutations") in the book, you should understand how to derive the EGF.

Comment: By the way, I personally find the presentation of this topic given in either *An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms, Second Edition* or *Analytic Combinatorics* by Sedgewick and Flajolet to be easier to follow than  the "cards, decks, and hands" in Wilf's book (although I think Wilf has, overall, the best introduction to GFs).